# Download thousands of files from a website in R

Tags: r

im trying to download thousands of files from a website : https://physionet.org/files/challenge-2019/1.0.0/training/training_setA

and I want the files appended into the same csv files rather than have thousands of files.

so far I've tried :

```
#install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)

#Grab filenames from separate URL
helplinks <- read_html("https://physionet.org/files/challenge-2019/1.0.0/training/training_setA/") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text(trim = T)

#Keep only filenames relevant for download
helplinks <- helplinks[grepl("srtm", helplinks)]

#Download files - make sure to adjust the `destfile` argument of the download.file function.
lapply(helplinks, function(x) download.file(sprintf("https://physionet.org/files/challenge-2019/1.0.0/training/training_setA/%s", x)
                                            , sprintf("D:/Desktop2/filea/%s", x)))
```

The only problem is that the file keeps getting written over by the different downloads rather than being appended or even creating a new file for each download.

Regards

Comment: Are you missing the formatting character `"%s"` in the destination file? `sprintf("D:/Desktop2/filea%s", x)`. If this solves it then the problem is just a typo and you should delete the question or it will be closed as simple typo.

Comment: `helplinks[grepl("srtm", helplinks)]` returns `character(0)`, it's an empty vector.

Comment: Nope.. That didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

The following works and downloaded 5 files. Note that the return values of `download.file` are all zero for success.

I have created a variable `destfile_format_string` because I downloaded the files to a different directory than the question's directory.

```r
library(rvest)

#Grab filenames from separate URL
helplinks <- read_html("https://physionet.org/files/challenge-2019/1.0.0/training/training_setA/") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text(trim = T)

#Keep only filenames relevant for download
helplinks <- helplinks[grepl("\\.psv", helplinks)]

helplinks[1:5]
#> [1] "p000001.psv" "p000002.psv" "p000003.psv" "p000004.psv" "p000005.psv"

destfile_format_string <- "~/Temp/filea%s"
lapply(helplinks[1:5], function(x) {
  srcfile <- sprintf("https://physionet.org/files/challenge-2019/1.0.0/training/training_setA/%s", x)
  destfile <- sprintf(destfile_format_string, x)
  download.file(srcfile, destfile)
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0

fls <- list.files(path = "~/Temp", pattern = "\\.psv$", full.names = TRUE)
info <- do.call(rbind, lapply(fls, file.info))
row.names(info) <- basename(fls)
info[1:3]
#>                  size isdir mode
#> fileap000001.psv 9117 FALSE  666
#> fileap000002.psv 3888 FALSE  666
#> fileap000003.psv 7977 FALSE  666
#> fileap000004.psv 4900 FALSE  666
#> fileap000005.psv 7899 FALSE  666
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: do you know of a way to download all the files into 1 csv file as suppose to having thousands of different text files

Comment: @Olayemi No, I don't. And I don't believe that's what you should do. If something goes wrong you would have to repeat all the downloads. After downloading the files you can read them and `rbind` them all in one data set, then save to disk.

Comment: ok ill do that thanks